# jQuery cycle + Fancybox plugins frame size problems

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to use the jQuery Cycle plugin with the Fancybox plugin. Almost everything is working at this point; fancybox opens, displays contents, contents cycle. The issue I'm running into is that the container isn't resizing automatically to fit to the images. The code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/scripts/jquery.cycle.lite.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#launcher").fancybox({
        autoScale: true
    });
})
$(function(){
    $('#slides').cycle({ 
    timeout:    8000,
    speed:      1000,
    pause: true,
    containerResize: 1,
    fit: 1
    });
});
</script>

   <div id="launcher">
      <div id="slides">
          <img src="/assets/images/VideoSlides/slide1.png">
          <img src="/assets/images/VideoSlides/slide2.png">
          <img src="/assets/images/VideoSlides/slide3.png">
      </div>
   </div>
```

As you can see, I've tried adding the various attributes to the functions to force it to autosize but they didn't have any effect. Setting the style of either div does size the frame accordingly, but I'd rather not have the frame at a fixed size. Anyone done anything like this before?

Comment: You should set a jsfiddle to let us test it

Comment: Isn't the option called "autoResize" not "autoScale"?

Comment: I've tried "autoSize" and "autoResize" as well, but neither worked. roasted, I'm working on a jsfiddle.

Comment: Well this is weird. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R43xY/. Except that every works fine in there. Not sure what that's about.

Comment: I can't edit that above comment anymore, but it's working because the images are the same size. If you resize an image, you'll see that the frame sizes to the largest height and width of all images in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no simple solution how to combine these two plugins so that fancyBox would resize before Cycle changes next image.

But, fancyBox2 already has built-in slideshow, why don`t you use that instead? You can activate it on the start using "autoPlay" option and use "playSpeed" to change speed. Quick example:

```
$("#launcher").click(function() {

    $.fancybox.open( $("#slides img"), {
        autoPlay   : true,
        playSpeed  : 2000,
        prevEffect : 'fade',
        nextEffect : 'fade'
    });

    return false;
});
```

See - http://jsfiddle.net/3SQt4/

Comment: I'll keep the built-in slide show in mind. Really the only reason I went with the Cycle plugin was to allow for the option of cycling non-pictures. If I'm able to convince the boss to stick with pictures, then I don't see why I can't use your suggestion. Thanks.